# CMD ignores first input

Tags: cmd

The following programm ignores the first input, will ask again and only then accept the input.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
IF EXIST C:\Windows\notepad.exe (
    :confirm
    SET /P confirm="overwrite? yn "
    echo entered: %confirm%
    IF /I "%confirm%"=="y" GOTO overwrite
    IF /I "%confirm%"=="n" GOTO no
    GOTO confirm
    :no
    echo You selected no.
    exit 1
    :overwrite
    echo You selected yes.
)
```

Entering `y<ENTER>`, `y<ENTERY>` will result in the output:

```
overwrite? yn y
entered:
overwrite? yn y
entered: y
You selected yes.
```

Entering `y<ENTER>`, `n<ENTER>` will result in the output:

```
overwrite? yn y
entered:
overwrite? yn n
entered: n
You selected no.
```

I start the programm with `cmd /k input-test.cmd`.

Removing the `IF EXIST` will remove that bug.

Comment: Don't use `goto :Label` within a code block; it breaks the block context!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'd need [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082).
And DON'T use `goto`s and Labels inside a code block! The `goto confirm` breaks your code block, so delayed expansion isn't applied any more (that's why it works the second time).

But with a slight change of your logic you don't need the code block at all:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
IF NOT EXIST C:\Windows\notepad.exe GOTO :eof
:confirm
SET /P confirm="overwrite? yn "
echo entered: %confirm%
IF /I "%confirm%"=="y" GOTO overwrite
IF /I "%confirm%"=="n" GOTO no
GOTO confirm
:no
echo You selected no.
exit 1
:overwrite
echo You selected yes.
```

Also for such simple user questions, the [choice](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) command is far better suited than `set /p`. It does it's own errorhandling, so it reduces your code to:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
IF NOT EXIST C:\Windows\notepad.exe exit /b 2
choice /c YN /m overwrite?
IF errorlevel 2 goto no
if errorlevel 1 goto overwrite

:no
echo You selected no.
exit /b 1
:overwrite
echo You selected yes.
```

Comment: The choice command looks interesting, but I couldn't find out on which platforms it is available. I am interested in running my script on Windows XP and on Windows CE 5 and 7, which uses PocketCMD.

Comment: look [here](https://www.computerhope.com/choicehl.htm#availability) for availability. Note: there was a slight syntax change between XP and VISTA